# Can't call my light and unlight methods in my if else statement

Tags: android, if-statement

```
buttonToggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {   
        if(light_off.getVisibility() == ImageView.VISIBLE)
        {
                //turn light on,
                light();
        }   
        else 
        { 
                //turn light off
                unlight();
        }
    }
    }); 
}

public void light()
{
    light_on.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
    light_off.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);   
}

public void unlight()
{
    light_on.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
    light_off.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

}
```

I wasn't trying to be redundant in my code so i wanted to put my lighting and unlighting methods for my android app "lightbulb" into methods that i could invoke in my if and else statements. I am using Eclipse so naturally the "light()" and "unlight()" would turn blue to show that the methods are being recognized but in this case they aren't. I'm not very sure what's going wrong, i've tried including the light and unlight methods in the class itself but i get an error of something like "improperly placed construct".

Comment: could you post the whole function, `});` looks a bit suspicious

Comment: sorry about that but i've updated it.

Comment: make sure the methods are declared in the right scope